# ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY when running .net5.0 isolated function on localhost with HTTPS

Tags: c#, azure-functions, localhost, .net-5, http2

I have a .net5.0 azure function (in isolated mode) running on my localhost for development.  In order to perform testing with the rest of the system, I am trying to enable HTTPS support.

I'm running the function as

```
func host start --dotnet-isolated-debug --useHttps --cert <certificate.pfx> --password <password>
```

And the versions are

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       3.0.3568 Commit hash: e30a0ede85fd498199c28ad699ab2548593f759b  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.15828.0
```

The issue I'm running into is that Chrome gives me a ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY error any time I try to communicate with it.  I don't get these errors when using IIS or IISExpress, which use the same certificate and is using h2 just fine with Chrome, so i'm pretty sure this is a func-specific issue.

I've tried removing support for HTTP/2 support to force it back to HTTP/1.1, but the isolated function relies on grpc for communication and wont run with just 1.1.  I know grpc-web exists, but the release will not use it and I'm trying to keep the dev and prod differences as small as possible.

Does anyone have any ideas on things to try, or is it somehow just not supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I came to the conclusion that it wasn't a supported setup in the development server that runs the func, so i ended up setting up a local nginx.exe reserve proxy to act as an SSL endpoint for the func.

Kludgy, but got the job done.

Would still be interested if anyone else was able to solve this.